# Stripe session: how to add additional data?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

This is my session:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        try {
            const params = {
                submit_type: 'pay',
                mode: 'payment',
                payment_method_types: ['card'],
                billing_address_collection: 'auto',
                shipping_options: [{
                        shipping_rate: 'shr_1LdjWJA0PvM7uNfTBERqQFUg'
                    },
                    {
                        shipping_rate: 'shr_1LdjXUA0PvM7uNfTAg076Fc0'
                    },
                ],
                line_items: req.body.map((item) => {
                    const img = item.image[0].asset._ref;
                    const newImage = img.replace('image-', 'https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w1sxln47/dev/').replace('-jpg', '.jpg')
                    return {
                        price_data: {
                            currency: 'eur',
                            product_data: {
                                name: item.name,
                                images: [newImage],
                                description: item.details
                            },
                            unit_amount: item.price * 100,
                        },
                        adjustable_quantity: {
                            enabled: true,
                            minimum: 1,
                        },
                        quantity: item.quantity,
                    }
                }),
                success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
                cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
            }
            // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
            const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(params);
            res.status(200).json(session)
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
        }
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
        res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
    }
}
```

And I have a object with a object called "dress".
Path to dress will be item.dress.height/etc
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaXXH.png)

How can I pass additional parameters to stripe? I tried to use metadata, but doesn't work with dynamic data. I need to pass my "dress" object to stripe success payment page. Thanks.

Comment: I don't recommend storing an object as a metadata since metadata is [limited to 50 keys](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) and it might not be enough in the future if you have multiple objects. The recommended way is to store the dress information in your database and give it a dress ID, then set the ID as a metadata in the Session. After the payment is completed, you can use this dress ID to retrieve the relevant dress information.

Answer (score 1):

you add it to the `metadata`

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    success_url: `url`,
    // if payment fails
    cancel_url: `fallbackUrl`,
    customer_email: req.user.email,
    client_reference_id: req.query.roomId,
    // those metadatas will be stored in session. additional information
    metadata: { checkInDate, checkOutDate, daysOfStay },
   //....   
  });
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/EPxeClW.png I'm actually trying to map it https://i.imgur.com/mlUhjgN.png But I'm doing something wrong.